# uploading files from azure mobile windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have an app with working facebook authenticatio. Now I want to enable the users to be able to upload files from the app, I want to know the code ONLY for uploading the file to my Azure Cloud Storage in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload directly from mobile device to your Azure Storage than you might want to look into Azure Storage Restful API (BLOBS) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx)

You can use for example method like `Put Blob` (API documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx ) to upload from your mobile device.

EDIT:

If you code your app in C# than you don't need to use the restful api, but use directly .NET wrappers of the Azure Storage
You can find a great tutorial and example here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: Thanks. But now I am facing another problem. I have downloaded the nuGet of Windows Azure Storage but I am not able to include it in my cs file (using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;). The error says that the type or namespace name 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.

Comment: That's wierd, are you sure you selected the project you're working on when you installed the package from nuget?